# Overwrite or don't copy?

Tags: linux, files, cp

I'm trying to copy a file only if it already exists, not if it doesn't, basically overwrite only on Linux. Does anyone know a solution?

I basically need to "look" for a folder then if a file exists, it overwrites in destination (recursive)

Answer (score 4):

Although there's a small race condition you could use something like this:

```
src=from.txt
dst=to.txt

[[ -f "$dst" ]] && cp -fp "$src" "$dst"
```

The `[[ ... ]]` operations checks to to see if the file already exists, and if it does the `&&` allows the copy to proceed.

If you have `rsync` you can do it directly (the `--existing` flag tells `rsync` only to update files that already exist):

```
rsync --existing --archive "$src" "$dst"
```